# FuelPHP custom environments

Tags: fuelphp

I'm moving an existing FuelPHP application across to a new environment, and I've reached the point where I could really do with adding another environment beyond the default 4 (ie. development, test, stage, production), which are all already in use elsewhere.

Is there any reasonably straightforward way of adding an extra environment to FuelPHP? If there is, I'd appreciate any guidance on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible but its not documented any where , here is the hacked approach that I found after looking at your posting

Below are the steps to create custom environment in FUel php application

for example you need to call your new environment as 'experiment' then

1 . Create a folder called experiment inside fuel/app/config directory

2 . create db.php file inside fuel/app/config/experiment directory with below contents you can add your other config but below are the default DB configurations  ( change it according to your platform ) also other migration files could be copied to this folder from other environment

```
return array(
    'default' => array(
        'connection'  => array(
            'dsn'        => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourappdatabasename',
            'username'   => 'yourDBuname',
            'password'   =>  'yourDBpassword',
        ),
    ),
);
```

3 . Next change the env name inside Fuel/app/bootstrap.php file

```
Fuel::$env = (isset($_SERVER['FUEL_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['FUEL_ENV'] : Fuel::EXPERIMENT);
```

4 . Then open Fuel/core/classes/Fuel.php file and add a new constant to Fuel class like below at the top of the class , I think you could find other environments also declared there .

```
const EXPERIMENT = 'experiment';
```

And that's all you have created a new custom environment in Fuel php application ,

> NOTE : - this approach is a hacked approach not officially documented
>   any where
>
> Posting here by hoping it may help you or others with similar
>   requirements

**EDIT : - This is for versions > 1.5**

Step 1 and step 2 are same

3 . (Assuming you're using Apache) set FUEL_ENV server variable to your new environment name by adding the following line to your VirtualHost configuration:

```
SetEnv FUEL_ENV experiment
```

That's all there is to it (on Apache, anyway). No need to add a const to core/fuel.php (as per the pre-defined environments). This is unnecessary and will only make it difficult to upgrade Fuel's core.

Comment: There is no reason for "hacking". FuelPHP supports an unlimited amount of environments as of v1.5. Just pick any string you like.

The constants in the Fuel class are there just for easy comparison, and used internally in the framework. They are not needed anywhere for a custom environment to work.

In step 3, simply use 'experiment' instead of the constant.

Comment: and p.s. Never change code in the core, you'll have a nightmare on your hands when you have to upgrade to a new release. If you feel you NEED to change something, override the core class in your application, and make your changes there.

Comment: @WanWizard Please understand the posting here , the person here is already using all the four environments defined and he needs to add another one along with the existing thing ,

Comment: @WanWizard Since you are the project Lead of FuelPHp project  why don't you post an answer here , with proper steps , it really helps others , and also If I simply pick a string of my desire and set at 3rd step its throwing an error , And I am using version less than 1.5 , and also person here has not specified any thing related to version of FuelPHP .

Comment: Thanks to both of you, and sorry I'm slow replying - I was waiting for a chance to test this. @aravind.udayashankara: WanWizard is correct, it turns out you can use any environment name. The step you are missing is to set 'FUEL_ENV' in your VirtualHost. If you don't mind, I'll edit your answer to remove the unnecessary steps, and then I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: @Nick F Sure , But just mention the version what you are using , the solution what I posted is for less than 1.5

Comment: @NickF I myself edited the post because , your edit was making lot of changes to original post and It was also rejected by moderators.